# How to generate the model browser structure using the sdb database

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to reacreate the model browser structure, but so far I haven't been sucessfull, I'm trying to join the parents and childs to reacrete the structure in the viewer.

**One of my requirements is to use the model.sdb database, so I can't use the tree structure inside the viewer. (Viewer API) OR the model derivative API**

So anything between a SQL query and a linq expression would solve my problem.

Thanks!

```
        var queryBranches = universe.Where(o => o.ObjectsEav.Any(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "child" && eav.Attribute.Category == "__child__"));
        var queryLeafs = universe.Where(o => o.ObjectsEav.Any(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent" && eav.Attribute.Category == "__parent__")).Except(queryBranches);

//Get Structure
foreach (var leaf in leafs)
{
    var leafAttr = leaf.ObjectsEav.FirstOrDefault(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent");
    if (leafAttr == null)
        leafAttr = leaf.ObjectsEav.FirstOrDefault(eav => eav.Attribute.Name == "parent");

    ...

}
```

**One of my requirements is to use the model.sdb database, so I can't use the tree structure inside the viewer. (Viewer API) OR the model derivative API**.

Answer (score 1):

You can either query the property db in [client browser](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-viewer-data-serverlessly-thumbnails-screesnshots-and-serverless-upload) or in your [backend](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-propdb-reader-demo).

Alternatively try `model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction():Promise` to execute function in worker thread against the PropertyDatabase instance:

```
 executeUserFunction(function(pdb) {
         var dbId = 1;
         pdb.enumObjectProperties(dbId, function(propId, valueId) {
               // do stuff
         });
    })
```

Comment: In the model browser (inside de viewer) we have a hierarchical structure, not every object in the database must appear in the model browser. We have entities in the database like sheets and metadata that doesn't appear in the model browser. What you are suggesting is a full query in the database. That's absolutely not what I want.

Comment: `One of my requirements is to use the model.sdb database, o anything between a SQL query and a linq expression would solve my problem` and hence my answer to query against the sdb to fetch the model data there and structure them to your requirements

Comment: The relation database does not have the hierarchical structure, that's why i need to make the correct queries to mount that structure, like first I query for all categories, then. I'm sorry I was unable to effectively show that on my question. It's very hard to do that kind of reverse engineering in a complex database structure like the model.sdb. We have attributes like parent/children/categories/RC/RF/RFT, and what I wanted is what filters do I need to use to get the correct categories... Probably with that I could then get the childs recursively and achieve the desired structure.